# Have Lambda function dispatch a task and return response right away

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Im a little confused since AWS has a lot of features and I do not know what to use.

So, I was creating a Lambda function that does a lot of stuff with a remote web, process could last at least a minute.

So my idea was creating an API that calls this lambda, have lambda create an unique ID and return a response right away to the client with a token., save this token to a DB.
Then have lambda process all this stuff with a remote web and, when it finishes, save the results to the DB and a bucket (a file), so this result is ready to deliver when the client makes another call to another API that makes a query to the DB to know the status of this process.

Thing is, it seems that if a response is sent from the handler, lambda terminates the execution, Im afraid the processing with the remote web will never finish.

I have read that step functions is the way to go, but I cant figure out which service will take the processing, ¿maybe another lambda?

Is there another service that is more suitable for this type of work?, this process involves scrapping a page and downloading files, is written in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read that step functions is the way to go, but I cant figure
> out which service will take the processing, ¿maybe another lambda?

Yes, another Lambda function would do the background processing. You could also just have the first Lambda invoke a second Lambda directly, without using Step Functions. Or the first Lambda could place the task info in an SQS queue that another Lambda polls.

> Is there another service that is more suitable for this type of work?

Lambda functions are fine for this. You just need to split your task into multiple functions somehow, either by one Lambda calling the other directly, or by using Step Functions, or an SQS queue or something.

Comment: It seems that is more flexible that I imagined it would be, thank you for your response!, AWS has a lot of services, sometimes is a little overwhelming.